# Is it true that one who put ash to their forehead will go for Kailas after death?

Tags: rebirth, brahman

Is it true that one who put ash to their forehead will go for Kailasa after death?

This belief is trusted by smartha brahmins community

Comment: It is true if you have faith. But that does not mean one can do whatever He wants after applying ash on His forehead :). All the best!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question itself answers that this is a belief. If you have true faith in this belief, follow it. But is it the only criteria? Definitely no.

Realization is what separates us mortals from the one residing in Kailasa. To attain realization or libertaion, you must follow 8 fold paths in Yoga of patanjali (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoga_Sutras_of_Patanjali#The_eight_limbs_of_Yoga)
and attain Nirvikalpa samadhi. This is possible only under a guidance of a guru. Hence first find a guru for your as per your spiritual and materialistic needs.

Comment: Where to find guru? do we need to roam around or guru by himself will search us...?

Comment: As per sages, if you have spiritual maturity, Guru will come near you. This is as per Yogananda's books http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paramahansa_Yogananda

Comment: @Mithun one need not run after Gurus. When the devotee has sincere faith, the Guru will Himself manifest before the devotee. All the best

Answer (score 1):

@Mithun - There is a hidden meaning in this on putting ash in forehead. It's not directly Ash, then if that's the case many would have gone to Kailash by now.

Here Ash symbolically represents your sexual energy which is white. You need to raise your sexual energy and stop it inbetween the eyebrows which is called இமயமைலை. Eyebrows in Tamil called = இமை and center point between that is மையம் and joining these two in Tamil will give you Himalayas where Lord Shiva resides.

To know more about the God, Atman, you need to explore our Indian languages than these English. Indian languages has many hidden meanings and things which will make you know God.

Comment: It's always better to cite some sources in your answer in order to prevent the posts either getting converted to comments or deleted. Do cite some sources in answer. It's mandatory on this site.

Comment: Certain true knowledge is not there in internet is what I have seen. This is there in Thirumoolar thirumandhiram but not the one which we have in internet.

Comment: @ParabrahmanJyoti - can you convert this: இமயமைலை. and இமை. Did not understand